# Make div clickable and use CommandName="Select"

Tags: asp.net, datalist

This code below works fine, when I click on the `LinkButton` the select will get fired.

However I have a hover style on the `div` so that it will change color if the mouse enters. This is confusing for users because when they click on the `div` nothing happens, only when they click on the `LinkButton`.

I want the `CommandName="Select"` to fire when a user clicks on the `div`. How can I do this?

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <div class="Card">
        <h4>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="SelectButton" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' CommandName="Select" runat="server"/> 
        </h4>
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("date") %>' />
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("location") %>' />
        <br />
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Please read about [formatting on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issues by placing the `LinkButton` outside the `div`. Now the whole `div` is clickable in the `DataList`.

```xml
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton CommandName="Select" runat="server">
        <div class="Card">
            <h4>
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
            </h4>
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("date") %>' />
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("location") %>' />
            <br />
        </div>
    </asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jquery` to trigger click event of button on click of the div

```
$("#Card").click(function(){
    $("[id$=SelectButton]").trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: OK searched this code wont work because there is no #SelectButton the id will be id="ContentPlaceHolder1_DataList1_SelectButton_0" so...

Comment: @IvoOostwegel updated the answer to work using ends with selector

Comment: No that is no solution this is what the id's look like
id="ContentPlaceHolder1_DataList1_SelectButton_0"
id="ContentPlaceHolder1_DataList1_SelectButton_1"
id="ContentPlaceHolder1_DataList1_SelectButton_2"
id="ContentPlaceHolder1_DataList1_SelectButton_3"
etc